# How do I manipulate a dom element on the same level as the current one? - jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

Say I have the following:

```
<ul>
   <li><img src='test.png'>    
       <div id=parentDiv>
           <div><img='click-me-icon.png'></div>
       </div>
   </li> 
</ul>
```

What I would like to do, is when the innermost `<img>` is clicked, I want to add a border to the outermost `<img>`. How do I do that?

I have all the other code down...i.e. I would do something like:

```
$('ul li div div img').click(function() {
    $(this).css({ 'border' : '1px solid green' });
});
```

I am just not sure what selector/function to put in place of $(this) in the above code snippet.

Comment: @Amirouche nevermind dude. Already been solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit** after seeing update to OP:

```
$('ul li div div img').click(function() {
    $(this).parents("li").children("img").css({ 'border' : '1px solid green' });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('ul li div div img').click(function() {
    $('img:eq(0)',$(this).closest('li')).css({ 'border' : '1px solid green' });
});
```

**EDITv3** That's what I was looking for. A different way to get to the same solution, but wanted to post the working version. ;-)

Comment: I updated the question to add the code escape formatting. I also updated the HTML code to better reflect a closer representation of what my structure looks like. calling parent() won't work.

Comment: This seemed very promising, but it doesn't work. See: http://jsfiddle.net/SB4m2/  I feel like you are on the right track though :)

Comment: @mar or bard, img border works if you use outline property, but agian outline property doesn't work for IE, so try to give border for its parent which is li or wrap it around another div

Comment: Thanks for trying, but Andrew got it.

Comment: Fixed the answer, used a different method. You were right, it was selecting the whole, but just was how I was referencing the selector. My apologies for taking 3 revisions. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

your code looks correct.it addes div border to the div as , that is the current item in the click

I made example from your code here

http://jsfiddle.net/QzRUE/

let me know if you need anything else

if you want for parent item you can do this

```
$(this).parent().css({ 'border' : '1px solid green' });
```

Comment: That doesn't work in this case. I have updated the HTML in the question. I also forked a new JS Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/etmNH/1/ - so you can see more accurately what I am working with. I want the higher image to be highlighted, when the deeper image is clicked. Thanks.

Comment: @for image borders its outline , but it doesn't work for IE , so please wrap it over a div or something and give a border...

Comment: Thanks for trying, but Andrew got it.